# AWS Cloud formation script to create and execute change set

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am using the following AWS Cli Cloud Formation commands to create and then execute and change set:

```
aws cloudformation create-change-set --change-set-name change-set-1
aws cloudformation execute-change-set --change-set-name change-set-1
```

However the first command returns before the the change set has been created, the if I execute the second command immediately it fails.

Solutions I have considered:

1. Adding a delay between the two commands.
2. Repeating the second command until it succeeds.

Both of these have their problems.

Ideally there would be an option on the create-change-set command to execute immediately, or to run synchronously and not return until the change set has been created.

Has anyone ever tried this and come up with a better solution than me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't require the intermediate step of creating a change set and then executing it (as we didn't) then use the `update-stack` sub command.

`aws cloudformation update-stack --stack-name myStack --template-url ...`

Answer (score 2):

I haven't personally tried it, but maybe you could use the command [list-change-sets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/list-change-sets.html) to loop until your change set is with a status **CREATE_COMPLETE**, and then execute your second command.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is a better suggestion than both of mine. Still not ideal obviously, as Im sure you would agree, but a possibility.

Comment: It's not optimal, I'll give you that, however the create-change-set guide does mention _"To check the status of the change set or to review it, use the describe-change-set action."_ So that's another command to try. The best solution would be some sort of CloudWatch Event that fired up when the change set creation was done, but I don't see something like that currently available.

Comment: This is definitely not desirable. Using the `aws cloudformation wait` as @Latruffe suggests is by far the better approach.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by using the following sequence :

```
aws cloudformation create-change-set
aws cloudformation wait change-set-create-complete
aws cloudformation execute-change-set
aws cloudformation wait stack-create-complete
```

Hope it will help.